# Using Oauth for authentication from a browser extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm creating a browser extension to add functionality to some websites and I'm pairing it with my own web app/ api backend. I want authenticate users who `POST` to the api. And I'm using the Doorkeeper gem with a Rails app to make my app an Oauth2 provider.

The Google page on the topic (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) says the client needs to register with the app (I have a sign up page set up) and then use

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {'url': '<url-to-do-auth>', 'interactive': true},
  function(redirect_url) { /* Extract token from redirect_url */ });
```

to hand the oauth

with

`https://www.website-of-provider-with-user-photos.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&
redirect_uri=https://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb&response_type=token&scope=user_photos`

being an example of the `url`

So, my questions are:

1) Doorkeeper gives you an `app_id` and an `app secret` I don't see anywhere to put those in this process. And since it's an extension it's all public so I don't see the point in that anyway.

2) I don't see how the user is supposed to get a client_id. My idea is that when a user logs in that will trigger the extension to send an ajax request in the background which will get the client_id and then I can keep that in storage. And if it ever gets lost the user can log in again and get it resent.

But just sending a client id doesn't seem secure and really easy to brute force. Maybe you couldn't log in as someone particular but you could log in as lots of people if you just have one number to guess.

And if I do make it more secure doesn't that replace the functionality of the the token, or couldn't I get the token more directly?

Comment: The app id (or client id) should be sent in requests from the client this is used in most oauth apis as both a security measure and to enable throttling. The app secret is used when making server side requests with oauth.

Comment: Note that client id means the app that is accessing the oauth endpoint - not an individual user. The user is identified by the in the authentication token sent in a successful oauth authentication. https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/